# htaccess rewrite and pass top directory name

Tags: .htaccess

Below works for passing directory names while doing a htaccess rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /index.php?xa=$1&xb=$2&xc=$3&xd=$4 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /index.php?xa=$1&xb=$2&xc=$3 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+) /index.php?xa=$1&xb=$2 [NC]
```

However when adding to above, the final line to also catch server.com/whatever situations:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) /index.php?xa=$1 [NC]
```

I get a 500 server error...

How come?..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems:

- `RewriteCond` before first rule is being applied to very next `RewriteRule` only
- No anchors `$` in your regex for `RewriteRule`.

Here is the fixed code:

```
RewriteEngine On

# ignore all rules below from files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?xa=$1&xb=$2&xc=$3&xd=$4 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?xa=$1&xb=$2&xc=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?xa=$1&xb=$2 [L,QSA]
```